# Compare the triplets. Print two space-separated integers denoting the respective comparison points earned by Alice and Bob

Tags: java, data-structures

The question has the url link [hackerrankquestion](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-tripletshttp://)

I wrote this code :

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;



public class Solution {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a0 = in.nextInt();
        int a1 = in.nextInt();
        int a2 = in.nextInt();

        int b0 = in.nextInt();
        int b1 = in.nextInt();
        int b2 = in.nextInt();
        int[] result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(result[i] + (i != result.length - 1 ? " " : ""));
        }
        System.out.println("");


    }

    static int[] solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2){
        // Complete this function
        int resultA = 0;
        int resultB = 0;
        int[] arrA = {a0,a1,a2};
        int[] arrB = {b0,b1,b2};
        for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
            if (arrA[i] > arrB[i] && arrA[i] - arrB[i] != 0){
                resultA++;
            }else resultB++ ;
        }
        int[]  array = {resultA, resultB};
        return array;

    }
}
```

Didn't pass the test . Attaching the snapshot. [image]

then I manipulated the result B = -1 and hurray , I passed the test 
[image: test case passed]

Only to know the rest of the test cases I have failed.
[image]

Any insight please why is this happening to me.

Comment: This probably belongs on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, since your code is already working, just missing an edge case.

Comment: add all Constraints, mentioned on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I found bug in your logic, it's here

Here is the correct implementation of the solve method

```
  static int[] solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2){
    // Complete this function
    int resultA = 0;
    int resultB = 0;
    int[] arrA = {a0,a1,a2};
    int[] arrB = {b0,b1,b2};
    for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
        if (arrA[i] > arrB[i] && arrA[i] - arrB[i] != 0){
            resultA++;
        }else if(arrB[i] > arrA[i] && arrB[i] - arrA[i] != 0){resultB++ ;}
    }
    int[]  array = {resultA, resultB};
    return array;

}
```

So what is happening is, if values of A and B are equal then also you are incrementing B and that is not what you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code could be much simplified if the main function is modified as,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a0 = in.nextInt();
        int a1 = in.nextInt();
        int a2 = in.nextInt();
        int b0 = in.nextInt();
        int b1 = in.nextInt();
        int b2 = in.nextInt();
        int[] result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2);
        //for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          //  System.out.print(result[i] + (i != result.length - 1 ? " " : ""));
        //}
        System.out.println(result[0]+" "+result[1]);//much simplified format


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z,a,b,c,count_a=0,count_b=0;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);

    if(a>x)
    count_a++;
    if(a<x)
    count_b++;
    if(b>y)
    count_a++;
    if(b<y)
    count_b++;
    if(c>z)
    count_a++;
    if(c<z)
    count_b++;
    printf("%d %d",count_a,count_b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.